# scanf("%[^\n]s") works fine with normal variable but doesn't work with a structure variable in C

Tags: c, structure, scanf

I am using GCC compiler

I wanted to scan white character as well so I used `scanf("%[^\n]s",&name)` and it just worked fine.

say the code is

```
void main(){
    char name[20];
    scanf("%[^\n]s",&name);
    printf("%s",name);
}
```

but when i tried to use it with a structure variable the statement doesnt work anymore.

```
struct book { char name[20];};
main(){
    struct book buk[10];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter name of book %d",i+1);
        scanf("%[^\n]s",&buk[i].name);}
    }
```

The scanf statement just don't execute.

But if I use simple `scanf("%s",&name);` it works just fine.
Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: "*se simple `scanf("%s",&name);` it works just fine.*" it just seems to work fine. `scanf("%s",&name);` invokes undefined behaviour. `%s` expects a `char*`, which `&name` is not.

Comment: You've got an extra `s`.  You want `"%[^\n]"`, not `"%[^\n]s"`.  (But then as user3121023 has noted you really want `"%19[^\n]"`, or maybe `" %19[^\n]"`.  Or maybe skip `scanf` entirely, and use `fgets` instead.)

Comment: You should check the return value from `scanf()` to ensure it read what you expected.

Answer (score 3):

*I used `scanf("%[^\n]s",&name)` and it just worked fine ?* No, it doesn't work fine. Read the manual page of `scanf()` it says

> int scanf(const char *format, ...);

first argument is of `char*` type but `&name` is not of `char*`type.

This

```
char name[20]; 
scanf("%[^\n]s",&name);
```

Should be

```
scanf("%[^\n]",name);/* & is not needed as name itself address */
```

Also it should be just `"%[^\n]"` not `"%[^\n]s"`. Correct one is

```
scanf(" %19[^\n]",name); /* giving space before % prevents reading extra characters */
```

Also it's better to use `fgets()`. For e.g

```
 char *p = fgets(buk[i].name),sizeof(buk[i].name),stdin);
 if(p != NULL) {
      /* do some stuff */
 }
```

Side note, if you are using `fgets()` then you should be aware of the fact that `fgets()` store `\n` at the end of buffer. so you may want to replace  that `\n` with  `\0`, for that you can use `strcspn()` or do it manually.

**Edit :** Note that `stdin` stream is line buffered i.e after `scanf("%[^\n]",name);` new line character `\n` stays in `stdin` stream and if  you are scanning data again second time, it may fail by not storing anything in `name` and may invokes undefined behavior. So first and foremost check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: Good points, you should also explain that the newline stays in the input stream after `"%[^\n]"` and the next `"%[^\n]"` will fail if on an empty line. Your solution with `" %[^\n]"` skips the newline and any other whitespace, but also skips any empty lines, which is not necessarily the expected behavior.

Comment: The behavior of `scanf()` is not exactly what you hint: it will not *ignore* the next input, it will fail and return `0`, leaving the destination array untouched, potentially leading to undefined behavior if the user does not check the return value, as is common practice.

Comment: Thanks @chqrlie Edited.